# Assign value to hidden input array element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three input array elements and two of them are hidden

defiend in javascript as:

```
   var via_route = document.getElementsByName('via_route[]');
    var viaLatitude = document.getElementsByName('via_route_lat[]'); --hidden in form
    var viaLongitude = document.getElementsByName('via_route_long[]'); -- hidden elememnt
    
var viaAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputw,{types:['address']});
            //}
        
            viaAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(event) {
            var place = viaAutocomplete.getPlace();

                if (place.hasOwnProperty('place_id')) {
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                            // window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                            return;
                    }                   
                    console.log('vlonh: '+vlength);
                    viaLatitude.value = place.geometry.location.lat();
                    viaLongitude.value = place.geometry.location.lng();
                    
                    console.log('vlonh2: '+viaLongitude.value);
                } else {
                    service.textSearch({
                            query: place.name
                    }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            viaLatitude.value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                            viaLongitude.value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

the value I want to get of all these three above arrays but only getting of `via_route` element

Edit:

```
for (var i = 0; i < via_route.length; i++) {
            var inputw = via_route[i];
            var viaAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputw,{types:['address']});
            //}
        
            viaAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(event) {
            var place = viaAutocomplete.getPlace();

                if (place.hasOwnProperty('place_id')) {
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                            // window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                            return;
                    }                   
                    console.log('vlonh: '+i);
                    viaLatitude[i].value = place.geometry.location.lat();
                    viaLongitude[i].value = place.geometry.location.lng();
                    
                    console.log('vlonh2: '+viaLongitude[i].value);
                } else {
                    service.textSearch({
                            query: place.name
                    }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            viaLatitude[i].value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                            viaLongitude[i].value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that since it is an array input, you can't directly assign value to it. You need to loop through the array and assign a value.

Example:

Here, I created two array input elements, and one is hidden.

```
<input type="text" name="arr1[]" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="arr2[]">
<p id="val1"></p>
<p id="val2"></p>
```

Now, I'll assign value through code:

```
 var input1 = document.getElementsByName("arr1[]");
 var input2 = document.getElementsByName("arr2[]");

 for(var i=0; i < input1.length; i++){
   input1[i].value = "10";
   document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML = "arr1[] value is: "+input1[i].value;

 }
 for(var j=0; j < input2.length; j++){
   input2[j].value = "20";
     document.getElementById("val2").innerHTML = "arr2[] value is: "+input2[j].value;
 }
```

It shows the values as 10,20. Here's the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PQ4r1RSRA21uENCE)

So, try looping as:

```
for(var i=0; i < viaLatitude.length; i++){
   viaLatitude[i].value = place.geometry.location.lat();  
 }

for(var j=0; i < viaLongitude.length; j++){
   viaLongitude[j].value = place.geometry.location.lng(); 
 }
 
 console.log(viaLatitude[0].value);
 console.log(viaLongitude[0].value);
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Can you share your code, how are you trying to update it? Share your HTML as well with the input elements.